# Accessing static members through class instances

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

In my application, I have many different types of "events". I have created an abstract class to define the general semantic of an event. To define particular events, I have extended the base event class to capture that.

```
abstract class Event {
    abstract type: EventType;
}

class UserBoughtProductEvent extends Event {
  type = new EventType('User Bought A Product');
}
```

Based on the above implementation there obviously is a problem when trying to instantiate 2 class instances of `UserBoughtProductEvent`. The `type` values of the 2 instances don't will not be equal since 2 different EventType objects have been instantiated.

A quick and obvious work around is to do something like the following

```
const eventType = new EventType('User Bought A Product');

class UserBoughtProductEvent extends Event {
  type = eventType
}
```

In a way, its like as though we have made type a "static" member that is accessible from a class instance. That's nice and all but the down side to this is that I now have to rely on every single specific event implementation to do something similar and hope that no developer accidentally instantiates a new EventType with every event instantiation. If there was a way to access truly static singletons across different instances that would be best.

So my question is, is there a way to do such a thing. A way to ensure that we have static singletons across instances that are modelled correctly via code?

The main reason I am after this is because I wanted to have a map to associated an event with an event handler.

So somewhere in my code, I wanted to do something like this

```
class Aggregate {
  private eventTypeToHandlerMap: Map<EventType, EventHandler>;
  
  constructor(map) {
    this.eventTypeToHandlerMap = map;
  }

  // other members and methods......
  
  applyEvent(event: Event) {
    // ------> im doing all this stuff for this if statement
    if(eventTypeToHandlerMap.has(event.type)) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // throw error or something
    }
  }
}
```

---

Edit: For the sake of completeness, this is EventType class implementation. It is not really required to answer this question, but some of you have asked for it

```
export class EventType {
    private readonly _value: string;

    constructor(input: string) {
        if(input.length === 0) {
            throw new Error('event type cannot be an empty string');
        } else {
            this._value = input;
        }
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now we don't know what `EventType` is, and even though it might not be crucial to the question, it's helpful to start from a common baseline.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll amend the above question to include EventType.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using actual `static` fields like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbnobm)?

Comment: Why do you want to rely on some internal property to compare types? If you have let's say one `event1` and one `event2` couldn't you just do this? `Object.getPrototypeOf(event1) === Object.getPrototypeOf(event2)`

Comment: I expanded my question to tell you why im doing this. Maybe I don't need a "type" member. But can you show me what should be done

Comment: Maybe you can use prototypical inheritance to avoid initializing like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYZogw)?  Does that work for you or not?  (Please mention @jcalz in a reply or I won't be notified.)